# Get Duplicates in List and Edit Item

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms, list

I need to get any items in a list that already exist and edit **BOTH** items to include a duplicate property.

I've attempted to get duplicates by doing:

```
var duplicates = LIST.Select((t, i) => new { Index = i, Text = t }).GroupBy(g => g.Text.PROPERTYTOSEARCGBY).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

However this returns me the property that is duplicated when however I need to get index of both of the records so that I can edit them using:

```
LIST[index1].FlaggedData = true;
LIST[index2].FlaggedData = true;
etc...
```

**How can I get the index of BOTH duplicate or multiple records?**

Comment: You already did what you ask - the each item of `duplicates` is `IGrouping`, i.e. enumerable containing the items that share the same key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `duplicates` is an `IGrouping` that can be iterated.  Each element in the enumeration will be an anonymous type that you defined to have 2 properties: `Index` and `Text`.

```
foreach (var grouping in duplicates)
{
    // This will contain the value that was grouped by:
    // - grouping.Key

    foreach (var pair in grouping)
    {
        // These properties are available
        //  - pair.Index
        //  - pair.Text

        // set the FlaggedData property
        pair.Text.FlaggedData = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was my misunderstanding of the proper use of grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the correct LINQ query to do what you want. Seems like your code to update the `Duplicate` flag is incorrect. You should use some code like below to update the Dupe flag

```
foreach (var group in duplicates) {
    foreach (var item in group) {
        LIST[item.Index].FlaggedData = true;
    }
}
```

or some more concise code like

```
foreach (var item in duplicates.SelectMany(item => item))
    item.Text.FlaggedData = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SelectMany

```
duplicates = LIST.Select((t, i) => new { Index = i, Text = t })
.GroupBy(g => g.Text.PROPERTYTOSEARCGBY)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.SelectMany(g => g, (g, x) => x.Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the index.
It's enough to group as you did and select the item themselves.

```
var duplicates = LIST.GroupBy(t => t.PROPERTYTOSEARCGBY)
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                     .SelectMany(t=>t);

foreach (var item in duplicates)
{
    item.FlaggedData = true;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
LIST.GroupBy(t => t.PROPERTYTOSEARCGBY)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(t=>t)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(t=>t.FlaggedData = true);
```